# ui-router and php with multiple views

Tags: php, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to build webapp with angularjs and php. I want to have several div's (with ng-view) that will load the menu pages which most will be php with own controlers. The issue is that i want it to show one at a time (like window) but any menu should upload to a new div, in other words a view that is free.

After searching and tried to learn i got to this bellow, but maybe i'm not understanding how it works.

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="appi">
<div class="btn" ng-click="setPage('Normal', 'hello.php', 'teste')">Hello</a>
<div class="btn" ng-clik="setPage('Normal', 'about.php', 'mainpage')">About</a>
<div ui-view="pag1"></div>
<div ui-view="pag2"></div>
<div ui-view="pag3"></div>
</div>
```

script :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router','ui.bootstrap']);
app.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
$stateProvider
    .state('pag1',{
        templateUrl: function ($stateParams){return $stateParams.page;},
        controllerProvider: function($stateParams){return $stateParams.type;}/*,
        onEnter: function(){$stateParams.type.},
        onExit: function(title){if(title){ ... do something ... }}*/
    })
    .state('pag2',{
        templateUrl: function ($stateParams){return $stateParams.page;},
        controllerProvider: function($stateParams){return $stateParams.type;}
    })
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('hello');}]);
app.run(function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
$rootScope.$state = $state;
$rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options){
    var xx="testeroot";
});});
app.controller('teste', function($scope, $filter, $http, $state, $stateParams) {
$http.defaults.headers.get = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'};
$scope.mytext="pageteste";});
app.controller('appi', function($scope, $filter, $http, $state, $stateParams) {
$scope.myPages = {'Normal':{'pag1':false, 'pag2':false}, 'Special':{'config':false, 'caixa':false}};
$scope.setPage = function($page, $url, $type){
    var currentState = $state.current; var currentName = $stateParams.page;var available = []; 
    angular.forEach($scope.myPages.Normal, function(value, key){if(value===false) available.push(key);})
    if($page=='Normal' && available.length==0) return "Por Motivos de Performance terá de fechar alguma janela antes de Abrir esta.";
    else if($page=='Normal' && available.length>0) {$state.go(available[0], {page:$url, type:$type},{location:'replace', notify:true});}
};});
app.controller('mainpage', function($scope, $filter, $http, $state, $stateParams) {
$http.defaults.headers.get = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'};
$http.get($scope.$resolve.$state$.url+"trata.php", {params:{action: 'getshops'}}).then(function (response) {
    $scope.mytot = response.data;
});});
```

the console has no errors, any idea what is wrong? or is the approach completely incorrect?

Comment: So after some obvious corrections (</a to </div and page to 'page') i can see that i get the php file, the only problem now is that is not showing in the div view. Does anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

After many searchs and tests, after strugle with extras-sticky views, etc.. i finally got to what i wanted. no ng-include and no view, simple service.

```
app.service('pager', ['$http', '$compile', '$q', '$templateCache', function($http, $compile, $q, $templateCache) {
var pages = {'Normal':['pag1.html', 'pag2.html'], 'Config':['config.html'],'Caixa': ['caixa.html']};
var pavailable = {'Normal':['pag1.html', 'pag2.html'], 'Config':['config.html'],'Caixa': ['caixa.html']};
var pinuse = [];
var template = {'pag1.html':'none','pag2.html':'none','pag3.html':'none','pag4.html':'none','pag5.html':'none','pag6.html':'none','config.html':'none','caixa.html':'none'};
return {
    getPages: function(type){return pavailable[type];},
    setPages: function(type, page){pavailable[type].splice(pavailable[type].indexOf(page),1);pinuse.push(page);},
    closePages: function(type, page) { pinuse.splice(pinuse.indexOf(page),1);pavailable[type].push(page);},
    getinuse: function(){return pinuse;},
    setTemplate: function(page, url, scope){
        var deferred = $q.defer(); template[page]=url; if(page==undefined || url=='none') $templateCache.put(page, '<p>none</p>'); 
        else $http.get(url).then(function(response){$templateCache.put(page, response.data);deferred.resolve($compile($templateCache.get(page))(scope));});
        return deferred.promise;
    },
    getTemplate: function(page){return $templateCache.get(page);}
}
}]);
```

with this div

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="appi">
<div class="btn" ng-click="setPage('Normal', 'teste/hello.php')">Hello</div>
<div class="btn" ng-click="setPage('Normal', 'about.php')">About</div>

<div id="pag1" >1</div>
<div id="pag2" >2</div>
</div>
```

i do have to thank this post ([Can I use $compile in an Angular service directly on a templateUrl instead of on raw HTML or a raw angular.element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26109658/can-i-use-compile-in-an-angular-service-directly-on-a-templateurl-instead-of-on)) the less correct answer saved me!!